# Install extra packages in Flatpak sandbox

Tags: flatpak

There are some Flatpak apps that have optional dependencies that are not bundled with the app. E.g the plotting package Veusz is available as a Flatpak and it can optionally use the Python package `h5py` to open HDF5 files. But `h5py` is not bundled with the Flatpak version. I saw a flatpak command `flatpak enter` that the documentation says allows us to

> Enter the flatpak sandbox.

So I started the Veusz flatpak app and used `flatpak ps` to get its PID. Then I tried `sudo flatpak enter PID pip3 install h5py` but it installed `h5py` in my host operating system!

TLDR; Is it possible to install custom packages (not just Python packages) in a Flatpak application's sandbox? If yes, how shall I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you need to [add an extension point and create a new package](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Extensions).

For example, add an extension point for the directory you need to add files (here `lib/GL`):

```
[Extension org.gnome.Platform.GL]
version=1.4
directory=lib/GL
```

and make a new flatpak package with the files to add (here `org.gnome.Platform.GL`).

In this case though, there may be some sort of issue. Looking at the metadata file for the Veusz flatpak [here](https://github.com/flathub/io.github.veusz.Veusz/blob/d7f4735e4418ec63e893a1287ab08e1d649427f5/io.github.veusz.Veusz.yaml#L84), they seem to be including hdf5 and h5py already. If you're missing this functionality you probably want to raise an issue in the repo.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry that I don't have enough reputation for an upvote.